# Move div to new line

Tags: css, html

I'm pretty new to CSS and it is still magic for me.
I want to have my div `movie_item_content_plot` on a new line. Currently I use `<br>` in HTML and this works fine. When I replace the `<br>` with `clear: both;` the div appears between `movie_item_poster` and `movie_item_toolbar` - but this is not what I want to have. It should be in `movie_item_content` but under `movie_item_year` and `movie_item_plot`.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/PCsBP/) is a fiddle to play around with.

### wanted layout (`<br>`)

[image: wanted layout]

### wrong layout (`clear: both;`)

[image: wrong layout]

### HTML

```
<div id="movie_item">
    <div class="movie_item_poster">
        <img src="..." style="max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%;">
    </div>

     <div id="movie_item_content">
        <div class="movie_item_content_title">title</div>
        <div class="movie_item_content_year">year</div>
        <br> <!-- I want to replace this br -->
        <div class="movie_item_content_plot">plot</div>
    </div>

    <div class="movie_item_toolbar">
        Lorem Ipsum...
    </div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
#movie_item {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 10px;
    height: 175px;
}

.movie_item_poster {
    float: left;
    height: 150px;
    width: 100px;
}

.movie_item_content {
    float: right;
}

.movie_item_content_title {
    float: left;
}

.movie_item_content_year {
    float: right;
}

.movie_item_content_plot {

}

.movie_item_toolbar {
    clear: both;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    width: 100%;
    height: 25px;
}
```

Comment: Note: breaks "<br>" are not made to structure you border-box model. They are only made to break texts in CDATA. Get along with "display:block" with CSS to create a break in your layout.

Comment: @Lucas Replace float by `display: block`. Put just `float:right` in the year, everything will be fine.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

What about something like this.

```
<div id="movie_item">
    <div class="movie_item_poster">
        <img src="..." style="max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%;">
    </div>

     <div id="movie_item_content">
        <div class="movie_item_content_year">year</div>
        <div class="movie_item_content_title">title</div>
        <div class="movie_item_content_plot">plot</div>
    </div>

    <div class="movie_item_toolbar">
        Lorem Ipsum...
    </div>
</div>
```

You don't have to float both `movie_item_poster` AND `movie_item_content`.  Just float one of them...

```
#movie_item {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 10px;
    height: 175px;
}

.movie_item_poster {
    float: left;
    height: 150px;
    width: 100px;
}

.movie_item_content {
    position: relative;
}

.movie_item_content_title {
}

.movie_item_content_year {
    float: right;
}

.movie_item_content_plot {
}

.movie_item_toolbar {
    clear: both;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    width: 100%;
    height: 25px;
}
```

[Here it is as a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/active_outdoorsman/Ns8U8/2/).

Comment: your fiddle shows the same result as I mentioned as wrong above? See the pictures ;)

Comment: Dohhh... didn't notice the word "plot" there in the middle.  I just removed a float from movie_item_content_title and moved movie_item_content_year up one line in the HTML and that should work better for you.  I also updated the JSFiddle.

Answer (score 4):

I've found that you can move div elements to the next line simply by setting the property
`Display: block;`

On each div.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```css
#movie_item {
        display: block;
        margin-top: 10px;
        height: 175px;
    }
    
    .movie_item_poster {
        float: left;
        height: 150px;
        width: 100px;
        background: red;
    }
    
    #movie_item_content {
        float: left;
        background: gold;
    }
    
    .movie_item_content_title {
        display: block;
    }
    
    .movie_item_content_year {
        float: right;
    }
    
    .movie_item_content_plot {
        display: block;
    
    }
    
    .movie_item_toolbar {
        clear: both;
        vertical-align: bottom;
        width: 100%;
        height: 25px;
    }
```

```html
    <div id="movie_item">
        <div class="movie_item_poster">
            <img src="..." style="max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%;">
        </div>
    
         <div id="movie_item_content">
                <div class="movie_item_content_year">(1890-)</div>
            <div class="movie_item_content_title">title my film is a long word</div>
            <div class="movie_item_content_plot">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officia, ratione, aliquam, earum, quibusdam libero rerum iusto exercitationem reiciendis illo corporis nulla ducimus suscipit nisi dolore explicabo. Accusantium porro reprehenderit ad!</div>
        </div>
    
        <div class="movie_item_toolbar">
            Lorem Ipsum...
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: That'll make the whole block go to a new line.